# Using $("[property=value]").click(), I want a delay between clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently selecting all the buttons on a page. using the following code.

```
$("button[data-capture=button123]").click(function(){
    ...some code on click
});
```

I end up clicking all the buttons at once, where as I would prefer clicking one at a time, using a delay between clicks.

Comment: How do you click all of them at once?

Comment: Search `js debounce`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should iterate over the various buttons and click them one by one. To do this you'll need to use a closure to remember the value of `i` inside the loop, like this:

```
var buttons = $('button[data-capture="button123"]'),
    delay = 500; // milliseconds

for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    (function(I) {
        buttons.eq(I).click(function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
                // some code
            }, delay * I);            
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: The `i` will be the same for all callbacks (`buttons.length`) as every callback uses the same value and because the `delay * i` is evaluated at the time when the button is clicked.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli When I enter the above code I get 'undefined'. What is the 'I' for?

Comment: @user1283103 That I is used in the anonymous function to remember the value of i. If you make a for setting a timeout with a function that uses the i then you'll end up with a lot of identycal functions with the same i (the last one in the for). With the I, you can store the value of each i and your functions will then remember it.

Answer (score 2):

I asume that you have multiple buttons repeating the data-capture

```
    var delay = 100;

    $("button[data-capture=button123]").each(function(i){
        $(this).click(function(){
           var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
             /* your code goes here*/
            }), delay * i );
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setTimeout`:

```
var buttonset = $('button[data-capture="button123"]');
buttonset.click(function(){
    setTimeout((function(){
    // code to implement
    }, 
    100//timeinterval in miliseconds can use variable also.
    );

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the `buttonset.click`  without the `for ... in` loop?  As the callback is called at the time when the button is clicked there should be no difference at all. You should not iterate over an jQuery result set using a `for ... in` as this will also iterate over all other properties like `length`, `wrap`, ... .

Comment: @t.niese in question he has mentioned for delay so i thought this will be good.

Comment: I don't know what the OP is really interested in. My comment was just about the bad style of your answer. Your current one does exactly the same as your originally without the incorrect use of the `for ... in`.

Comment: thanks for your comment.I am not that experience in these stuffs.just learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("button[data-capture=button123]").click(function(){
         $("button[data-capture=button123]").each(function(){
                // apply delay() here or  some setTimeout logic
         });
   });
```